# Jenkins Service Call failed > Server Error?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I am trying to run Jenkins on localhost:8080, in an Ubuntu VM. When I try to run a gradle script which creates a few jobs on jenkins, i get the following stack trace:

```
:ci:<job name>
Creating new item <item name> on http://localhost:8080/
:ci:<job name>FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Jenkins Service Call failed
> Server Error

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.service.JenkinsServiceException: Jenkins Service Call failed
    at com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.service.JenkinsRESTServiceImpl.createConfiguration(JenkinsRESTServiceImpl.groovy:112)
    at com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.service.JenkinsService$createConfiguration$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.tasks.UpdateJenkinsItemsTask$_doExecute_closure1$_closure2.doCall(UpdateJenkinsItemsTask.groovy:20)
    at com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.tasks.AbstractJenkinsTask$_eachServer_closure4.doCall(AbstractJenkinsTask.groovy:71)
    at com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.tasks.AbstractJenkinsTask.eachServer(AbstractJenkinsTask.groovy:69)
    at com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.tasks.UpdateJenkinsItemsTask$_doExecute_closure1.doCall(UpdateJenkinsItemsTask.groovy:16)
    at com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.tasks.UpdateJenkinsItemsTask.doExecute(UpdateJenkinsItemsTask.groovy:15)
    at com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.tasks.AbstractJenkinsTask.executeTask(AbstractJenkinsTask.groovy:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:227)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Server Error
    at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.defaultFailureHandler(RESTClient.java:263)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$1.handleResponse(HTTPBuilder.java:503)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:218)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:160)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:515)
    at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.post(RESTClient.java:141)
    at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient$post$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.service.JenkinsRESTServiceImpl.restServicePOST(JenkinsRESTServiceImpl.groovy:50)
    at com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.service.JenkinsRESTServiceImpl$restServicePOST$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.terrafolio.gradle.plugins.jenkins.service.JenkinsRESTServiceImpl.createConfiguration(JenkinsRESTServiceImpl.groovy:110)
    ... 75 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 25.892 secs
```

- Ways I've tried to debug this issue:

  - Making sure there is nothing wrong with the gradle script (it runs fine on our corporate jenkins server)
  - Disabling "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits"
  - Changing the of /var/lib permissions to 777
  - Running the docker image of jenkins
  - Trying different versions (latest, 1.651.3, 2.7.2)
  - Manually sending post requests to the jenkins server via postman

    - Causes `java.io.IOException: Failed to persist config.xml` error
  - Restarting jenkins
  - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Disable+security?showComments=true&showCommentArea=true#addcomment

Note: I am using the terrafolio plugin for gradle

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: so... where is the script?

Comment: i had the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the jenkins log at /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log while running the gradle script:

tail -f /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log